# PowerPoint doesn't run Videos on other computers even after using Package for CD

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I wanted to show a Presentation. When I run it on another computer, both the sounds and the vids didn't work. I found out about Package for CD and run it. The audio started to work on other computers, but the videos still ain't working. I am also including the audios and vids as the included files, but still, only the audios are working and the vids just show as thumbnails.

I am using PowerPoint 2007, Please help me if you have got any idea.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vids to play in PPT, two things have to happen:

- PPT has to be able to FIND the linked video file, and
- The CODEC required by the video must be installed in Windows

To keep links from breaking, you have to:

- Save the PPT at least once before adding any videos
- Put the video files in the same folder as the saved PPT
- Make sure that the videos and the PPT file stay together, in same folder, on any computer where you want to play the presentation.

Package for CD should have handled all of that correctly for you, or modified the presentation so that it works as though it did.

As for CODEC though, you might try inserting the video into a new presentation on the system where the vids aren't working.  If they still don't play, you need to figure out what codec was used and install it (or re-make the videos with a more common codec).

I'm not enough of a vid wiz to explain exactly how to do that; perhaps someone more knowledgeable will come along to fill in the blanks.  If not, google is our friend.

Answer (score 1):

It would work to save the original video file (not one copy pasted from the powerpoint presentation) in the pc. I assume you are the recipient of an emailed presentation. Make sure to have the videos in the ppt emailed as well.